# How to change the Combo box Selected Item color through MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Can any one give me some example on how to change the combo box selected item color through MVVM.
I am using WPF as a UI.

Comment: Look into Style triggers, data triggers

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewModel get selected item (if you are using ICollectionView then user CurrentItem) and in View change style of selected Item using  DataTrigger.

Answer (score -1):

This should help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9906687/1468507

Whether you're talking about selection or highlight.

**Edit (setting the selected text to red) :**
This should do the trick.

```
<ComboBox>
  <ComboBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBoxItem}}" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ComboBox.Resources>
...
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: I need to change the text color of the selected item in the combo box to red, not the background color of combo box selected item.